# Changes occur in my divs when I use the "a" tag

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css, bootstrap-4

Changes occur in my divs when I use the "a" tag.I wrote 600 lines of code and my site is breaking.
It should have no effect when I use the "a" tag.  NOTE: " TAG" i never classed.

Example:
[image: here is an example]

```
<a href="#">
    <div id="logokutu1" class="deneme ortalama neozel logoborder col col-md-a col-lg-a">
        <img width="100" height="22" src="marketplace logo/ne-lazimsa-logo.png">
    </div>
</a>
```

Comment: What is the intention of wrapping the `<div>` in the `<a>`?

Comment: I will add a link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally `<a>` have inline display and you must change display to block or inline block and then Give it your styles

for change `<a>` display just do like this

**html :**

```
<a class="test"></a>
```

**css :**

```
.test{
    display : inline-block
}
```

> or you can change display to `block` only

after this you can set whith and height and Whatever you want to `<a>` tag

Comment: how can I do that

Comment: @NurullahGüneyli Not the original poster, but you seem to be using bootstrap.  Bootstrap has display classes, so you could use either `d-block` or `d-inline-block` on the `<a>` tag: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/

Comment: @JosephMarikle and Kasra Habibeygi I tried what you said but did not change

Comment: In general, when you want to give style to this tag (like width and height) you must do this , if that is not worked use `.test{display : inline-block !important}`

Comment: I did but here is the result  https://hizliresim.com/C1XYzQ

Comment: i think you must give `#logokutu1` , `height : 100%` , if put your css in your question i can help you better

Comment: Thank you, we made it.

Comment: i glad to hear this